# Heroku Error: No such file or directory after Bamboo - Cedar upgrade

Tags: heroku, bamboo, cedar

I've upgraded my app from Bamboo to Cedar following the instructions [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-migration). My problem now is whenever I run any heroku command on the new heroku app I receive the following error

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate --app my-app  
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.1  
Error: No such file or directory
```

The error does not tell me which file is causing this problem so most of the related posts haven't been applicable to this particular problem

The same error occurs for `heroku run console`, or even `heroku run why_wont_this_work`

I attempted `heroku update`, was yelled at for not having the Heroku Toolbelt, installed that, and still get yelled at for not having the Heroku Toolbelt.

Comment: Did you try to remove and reinstall Heroku gem ? Then add gem 'heroku' to the Gemfile.

Comment: I did ya, eventually I just created a new heroku app and built on it slowly making sure everything worked along the way. Don't have an explanation for what was messing up before.

Comment: As for transitioning to heroku toolbelt and away from the old heroku gem, make sure also that your heroku toolbelt start script is on your path.  `which heroku` to see if you're still pointing at an old script.  Then ensure that `heroku` on your path will point to your latest toolbelt script, instead. (ex. put a soft link at /usr/local/bin/heroku that points to the toolbelt script, etc.)